# encoded parentheses in html variables in paypal payment url

Tags: paypal, url-encoding

I found a problem using parentheses in a variable used to create a url to start a paypal payment ()[paypal html payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)
For the paypal field *os2* the user enters

```
some text
```

and everything is ok.

If the user enters

```
some (text)
```

that is encoded to

```
some+%28text%29
```

and paypal redirects to the homepage.
Same behaviour on paypal sandbox.

This call works:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=myid&lc=IT&item_name=my_payments&currency_code=EUR&button_subtype=services&no_note=1&no_shipping=1&on0=operazione&os0=altro&on1=tipo&os1=persona&on2=pagante&os2=some+text&on3=causale&os3=prova+paypal&option_select0=altro&option_amount0=0.01&return=http://my.return.url&rm=2&cbt=Back&cancel_return=http://my.cancel.url&custom=mysaleid
```

This doesn't work:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=myid&lc=IT&item_name=my_payments&currency_code=EUR&button_subtype=services&no_note=1&no_shipping=1&on0=operazione&os0=altro&on1=tipo&os1=persona&on2=pagante&os2=some+%28text%29&on3=causale&os3=prova+paypal&option_select0=altro&option_amount0=0.01&return=http://my.return.url&rm=2&cbt=Back&cancel_return=http://my.cancel.url&custom=mysaleid
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a paypal bug?

thank you
  maxx

Comment: You're doing it wrong both times. It should be a POST, not a GET, and the request parameters should be in the request body, not the URL.

Comment: @EJP I'm using POST not GET. I simply copied the url from Firebug.

Comment: Then I repeat that the parameters should be on the body of the request.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean.
You are fixing your attention to the wrong detail.
The problem is with the content of one of the POST parameters, as I wrote in my OP, not with the way I reported as an example the 2 different calls.